# Is This The Right Way To Change Drives Using Terminal?

Tags: command-line, dual-boot, partitioning, mount, hard-drive

Well I am a newbie in Linux world. Everyday learning by working. I use dual booting and in one drive Windows 7 is installed and in another drive Ubuntu 14.04 LTS is installed. My first O/S was windows 7. There was few drives like Workshop, Movies, Soft etc. Now I was about to change drives in terminal to access files stored in different drives. After spending couple of hours I discovered a way to access different files in different drives. What I did is first of all I mounted lets say /dev/sda2 drive in /media/username folder using this command....

> $ sudo mount /dev/sda2/ media/username

Once mounted then I can easily change directories by using `cd` command.

Now my questions are...

1. Is this really a correct way to change drives to access files?
2. I can go forward like `$cd /media/username` but how to go backward?
   I mean go back to root or go back to media? In windows CMD I am
   using `cd..` to go one folder back. Is there any similar command for
   terminal?
3. What is the difference between drive and partition?
4. How to unmount a drive or any file?
5. My last question is as far as I know in Linux files are arranged
   under root `/` directory. If so then it might don't respect windows
   drive systems. If so then all files should be accessed without
   mounting any drive to /media/username folder?

Comment: This question seems a bit broad.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First, note there is a typo in `mount` your command. It should be:

```
$ sudo mount /dev/sda2 /media/username
```

Here `/dev/sda2` is the device (in this case, a hard drive's partition) you want to access, and `/media/username` is your *mountpoint*, i.e., the location in the filesystem where you want to mount the device.

To answer your questions:

1. Yes, using `cd` is the normal way to change directories. And `mount` is perfectly fine to mount devices that are not already mounted. If you mount it often, you may want to make an entry in `/etc/fstab` so that in the future you can mount a particular device to a particular mountpoint with self-defined options, e.g., by simply writing `mount /media/username`. You may even want to consider mounting it automatically, at boot time. There is a lot of excellent documentation on the subject. Just search for `fstab`.
2. I guess you want to do a bit of reading about the Linux filesystem. There's also good documentation for this, see, e.g., [here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/09/linux-file-system-structure/) for a short overview. `/` is the root folder in which *everything* is contained, organized in various subfolders. Here's a few hints concerning `cd`:

   - `cd` (without arguments) will get you to your home folder, typically `/home/username`
   - `cd -` will get you to the previous folder (where you were before you changed to the current folder)
   - `cd ..` will get you to the parent folder (one level up). This is equivalent to `cd..` in Windows CMD.
   - `cd /` will get you to the root folder, though I personally rarely need that.
3. A (hard) drive is actually a disk that you can store data on. It is usually divided into several partitions. Perhaps confusingly, in the Windows world these partitions are also called *drives*. This is not the case in the Linux world, though. We simply  call them partitions, or perhaps "devices" in a technical context.
4. To unmount a mounted device, use the command `sudo umount <MOUNTPOINT>`, e.g., in your example,

   ```
   sudo umount /media/username
   ```

   ...where `/media/username` is a mounted partition (you could also use `sudo umount /dev/sda2`, though this is perhaps less intuitive). Simply write `mount` (without arguments) to see a list of all currently mounted devices with their mountpoints.
5. In Linux, you have to mount each of your Windows "drives" on a separate mountpoint. You are completely free to choose where, and you already know how to do it, as you showed with your `mount` command. :)

Comment: Maybe you want to add that manually mounted drives usually go into `/mnt/somemountpoint` and `/media/user/somemountpoint` is used for automounting USB, CD, etc.

Comment: The command "man hier" should supply Mike with some interesting information about the filesystem tree

Comment: @MalteSkoruppa Thanks for such an explanatory answer. You spent significant amount of time for helping me. Many thanks man. :)